# How does one contact Canonical to suggest a change?

Tags: canonical

I am wanting to contact Canonical to suggest that they push all changelogs to changelog.ubuntu.com so that `apt-get changelog <package>` will work for PPAs too, but how do I contact Canonical about something like that? Or is there somewhere to file a bug report about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact [Launchpad support](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad).

But changelogs from PPA will never be added to `changelog.ubuntu.com`, because these are Personal Package Archives that are maintained by people who do not work for Canonical.

Canonical is not responsible for PPA at all.